# how to use self.response_body in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to stream a large amount of text from a controller to a view in real time and was pointed to using the following code as an example of how to handle the streaming

```
def home
   self.response_body = proc {|resp, out|
    10.times do |x|
        out.write "count = #{x}"
        sleep 1
    end
}
```

Now this code works in so much the content streams to a browser with 1 line appearing every second, however it doesn’t use the home.html.erb view I created instead it only renders a blank page with the streaming data on it

I’ve tried to embed it using various bits of erb code but cant get it to work and I’ve had a hunt around the web and cant see any clue as how to do this

Can anyone help?

I'm using Rails 3.0.7 and ruby 1.9.2, in dev I'm using unicorn as the rails server which handles the streaming

Cheers

Mike

Comment: Have you considered doing the streaming asynchronously?  I could be wrong, but you're not going to be able to stream inside of a layout.  You're replacing the response body with your periodic stream.  Ajax pattern here http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the response_body in the controller it will not render the view.  So I'm afraid you have to pick one or the other.  In fact, I've received an exception when I tried to send a response to the client via two different methods.  In my case it was send_data and self.response_body = ...